# gnu ld says undefined reference to `xxx(arg1, arg2)' in program with external hpp header

Tags: header-files, ld

just to make my kernel source code smaller, i spilt it into multiple headers.

(important, they are hpp headers, not h headers. so extern "C" {#include <that_stuff.hpp>} didn't do anything.)

while linking, gnu ld says "undefined reference to `xxx(arg1, arg2)'"

(the function "xxx(arg1, arg2)" is in the header)

how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your description seems, that you don't compile your .cc file with ***extern "C" { };*** - did you try a re-compile?
you can try to add the prefix ***extern "C" void xxx(int arg1, int arg2);***
in your header file.
If this don't work, make the same in your source file:
***extern "C" void xxx(int arg1, int arg2) { /* code */ }***

C .o file linkage does not show arguments for functions, only the name - commonly.
It can be changed, but in my knowing it is so like I write it.

Comment: it's a .cpp file and i did try it but it gave errors because i used function-overloading.

Comment: ok. if you do so, and I thinking, you would use C++ function in C code, then overloading does not work. Either you rename the C++ function, or just use one at each. This means, you have to do ***foo_func1( ) { }*** or ***foo_func2( ) { }***. But to avoid this, you can use a static "struct", in which you place entry points for each overloaded function. So you can have multiple "struct". But then, you have a little bit overload todo (save the entry points as #define or constexpr in your header.

Comment: but, to make things simple only i'm using overloading.

Comment: yes, you can do this. But then, you can't use C++ code (including object binary code) from C++ in C projects. C does not know C++ overloading. C++ is used mangled function names. So, if you have a look at a C object file (hex viewer), and at a C++ object file, you can see the differences: C .o: foo_test, and in C++ .o 8foo_testvvv - where the first 8 signs the function/class/namespace size in length, after this 8 chars (of function name) follows vvv - which indicates the arguments. it is internal different from compiler to compiler. I don't know it all in detail.

Comment: ok, ok, but all i want to know now is how to use overloaded functions from a header file incuded by the source code while linking (i'm linking it seperately with a linker script so that i can simulate the code as a .iso file on qemu)

Comment: simply? - you can't ! header files are used at compile time, not link time. ld scripts are used at link time. But ld scripts have nothing todo with C++ header files. If you would like to have a bootable ISO, you have to "static" build a kernel - with all the functions that the (program) calls. If you have a good linker, then uneccassary object files will not be linked. But commonly all object code is linked to one file. If you have this, then you have to extract the object file header. And you have to provide a boot block, that read the kernel entry code, which boots your entire kernel.

Comment: Hello, maybe too late... But I can point You in this direction of an old Project of me at my github.com Account:  https://github.com/paule32/deBlows   feel free to use it. I don't remember me on which Platform I tested it - but I think it was in 2016 on a Linux Workstation. Hope This Help's and give You an Example on "how to make" ... Good Luck